# How to create a WIndows Vista Installer including my own drivers

Tags: hard-drive, windows-vista, drivers, bsod, sata

I try to add a Syba SD-PEX40054 with Marvell 88SE9230 RAID Sata 3.0 PCIe card to my Workstation Intel s5000psl to pass from SATA 2.0 to SATA 3.0 and add HDD with SATA 3.0 specs. Now I have an issue, when I add the card to the motherboard and try to install Windows Vista x64, when the installer is booting and upload the drivers appear a BSOD, I need to create a customized installer with Windows Vista x64 and add the correct drivers to the new installer, I try with vLite but don't work like I setup, if someone can help me I appreciate. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To actually create an operating system installer that has added features one would have to poses a massive understanding of how the operating system installs and works- which few people have. Even if you were capable of doing such an install, it would not be much worth the trouble, unless you plan on installing it onto many different systems, and even still, there are better tools for that.

I would advise setting up the operating system as you want it with all of its drivers, and then creating a backup with Symantec Ghost to install unto other computers.

Though, judging by what information I could gather from your question,  there are many other problems that you need to fix before you even think about making a Ghost Backup.

Comment: That would be true if you were to attempt to reverse engineer the installer. However, Microsoft already provides tools for customisation of their images for deployment. See: WAIK.

Comment: Thanks, I try again with WAIK to turn off all the SATA storage controllers and only leave the driver that I need.

Comment: Really? thats a thing? wow, sweet!